# Detecting FireWire cable event within MFC C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, firewire

I'm trying to detect the event when a FireWire cable is plugged into the FireWire port of the PC withing MFC C++ app. I would also like to trigger this even myself as the FireWire connections drops and never is rediscovered withing unplugging the cable and plugging it back in.

Anyone have any experience trying to programmaticaly simulate a unplug-replug event?

Comment: Just the cable, or is there something on the other end of the cable?

Comment: There is a camera plugged in at the end of the cable.  Sorry I should have included that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can register yourself to receive device arrival messages. See the help for [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find an example on how to register yourself.

You can trigger a bus reset notification on the firewire bus, but I don't know if you can do this from user mode, without the help of a kernel mode module.